# How do I know which I/O allocation function to use (request_region VS. request_mem_region)?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

According to [Corbet and Rubini](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch09.pdf), to request an I/O port, one must use `request_region(unsigned long firstport, unsigned long len, const char *name)`. However they *also* mention to request I/O memory, one must use `request_mem_region(unsigned long firstaddr, unsigned long len, const char *name)` and then remap it with `ioremap(unsigned long phys_addr, unsigned long size)`. How do I know which kind of I/O I need (memory or port)?

Comment: Read the documentation for the device you're trying to talk to.

Comment: If it's PCI device, just map BAR(s), it will recognize the type automatically. Otherwise you have to know ahead what type of bus the device is using and how is supposed to communicate with.